# SCP fails on specific system

Tags: ssh, openssh, scp

I'm trying to SCP some files (both ways) to my raspberrypi. However, on ONLY my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, I am unable to SCP into it. Both ways, I can SSH into each other, both via password and passwordless login methods. On SCP however, after it asks for my password (in passwordless) it just hangs and doesn't transfer the files. Running `scp -vvv ...` yields the following truncated logs

```
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_SG.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_SG.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env P9K_TTY
debug3: Ignored env ZSH
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env P9K_SSH
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env GEM_HOME
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f ~/Desktop/saves
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

On another computer, a Macbook Pro, I can SCP just fine. This leads me to think that it is a problem specific to my desktop, but I cannot figure out what it is. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

EDIT: The full command run was `scp -vvv pi@driftcar:~/Desktop/recording.jpg ~/Desktop/`. driftcar is my ssh alias, I've tried keying the IP address directly as well but to no avail.

Comment: Please post the whole scp command you are trying to run. Do you connect to rPI through wifi or cable? As a blind shot, it seems like a variation of this (although that is really old post): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-restricted-modules-2.6.24/+bug/237894

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The command is actually just `scp -vvv pi@driftcar:~/Desktop/recording.jpg ~/Desktop/`. `driftcar` is my ssh alias, I've tried keying the IP address directly as well but to no avail.

Comment: Sure thing. Please update your question with the details then - in a few days, nobody will go through the comments looking for details. ;)